# How to move text to the same line as a button in Tailwind CSS

Tags: position, tailwind-css

I am a complete beginner to Tailwind CSS. How do I move the text **Sovereignty Music** to the same line as the **close icon** on the top. I want the answer in Tailwind CSS please. Code Below .

```html
<div className="w-72 bg-white text-gray-100 shadow-lg">
  <div className="p-7 text-sm h-full flex flex-col">
    <button className="text-slate-800 self-end hover:text-white hover:bg-black rounded-full p-2 transition ease-in-out delay-50 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-200 cursor-pointer">
      <SwitchHorizontalIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
    </button>
    <a className="flex space-x-5 p-5 text-slate-800">
      <MusicNoteIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
      <p className="font-semibold">Sovereignty Kingdom</p>
    </a>
    <nav className="flex items-center space-x-3 rounded-lg p-3 text-slate-800 hover:bg-black hover:text-white my-2 transition ease-in-out delay-50 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-200 cursor-pointer">
      <HomeIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
      <p>Home</p>
    </nav>
    <nav className="flex items-center space-x-3 rounded-lg p-3 text-slate-800 hover:bg-black hover:text-white my-2 transition ease-in-out delay-50 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-200 cursor-pointer">
      <TrendingUpIcon className="h-5 w-5" />
      <p>Trends</p>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap both `button` and `a` tag inside a `div` and give it `flex` and `justify-between` classes

you want it to look like this right?:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="w-72 bg-white text-gray-100 shadow-lg">
  
  <div class="p-7 text-sm h-full flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex  justify-between">
      <a class="flex  py-5 text-slate-800">
      <MusicNoteIcon class="h-5 w-5" />
      <p class="font-semibold">
        Sovereignty Kingdom
      </p>
    </a>
      <button class='text-slate-800 bg-red-500 self-center hover:text-white hover:bg-black rounded-full p-2 transition ease-in-out delay-50 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-200 cursor-pointer'>
        icon
      </button>           
    
    </div>
    <nav class="flex items-center space-x-3 rounded-lg p-3 text-slate-800 hover:bg-black hover:text-white my-2 transition ease-in-out delay-50 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-200 cursor-pointer">
      <HomeIcon class="h-5 w-5" />
      <p>Home</p>
    </nav>
    <nav class="flex items-center space-x-3 rounded-lg p-3 text-slate-800 hover:bg-black hover:text-white my-2 transition ease-in-out delay-50 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-200 cursor-pointer">
      <TrendingUpIcon class="h-5 w-5" />
      <p>Trends</p>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Dhaifallah . Thank you for your answer. It did work but the only problem is that the **icon** now is in an awkward position slightly below the Title **Sovereignty Kingdom**. So can you help me to rectify it.

Comment: Hello @JoshuaDaniel  There are two solutions, one by adding this class `self-center` to button, the second one would be specifying a height to the button like `h-12` and adding `items-center` to the `div` parent , have a look [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/iD2erPxeTz)

Comment: Hi again @Dhaifallah. Thank you again, the solution you gave me was helpful and it worked and made the icon closer to the position I was expecting. The problem now I am facing is that they both are touching and The thing I want is that the icon should be 2 to 3 pixels diagonally up to the right and the text **Sovereignty Kingdom** should not be affected in any way. Meaning that the text should be in one line only and the text **Kingdom** should not go to the next line. Please help me 

Comment: Hi again @JoshuaDaniel, to move the `button` first make the parent `div` `relative` then add this to the `button` `absolute right-[3px]`, the second problem is happening because the  `MusicNoteIcon` try make it like this `<MusicNoteIcon class="h-5 w-5" ></MusicNoteIcon>`  look [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/pn79I1x63Y)

Comment: You are Welcome dude! that would be by adding a `hidden` as the default not `sm:hidden` so it would be like this `hidden md:block`